# Define a unique sequence in XML

Tags: xml, xsd

Given XML

```xml
<properties>
    <prop1>3.9.0</prop1>
    <prop2>1.2.0</prop2>
    <prop2>1.2.1</prop2>
    <prop3>6.6.0</prop3>
</properties>
```

```
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="properties">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" processContents="skip"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

I want to prevent duplication of the prop2 tag (as shown in the sample) without limiting it in other ways. So how can I ensure the uniqueness of these properties without having to define them?

Or put another way, how can I define an XML sequence which acts as a set?

Answer (score 2):

In XSD 1.1, with an assertion:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:element name="root">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="properties">
          <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" processContents="skip"/>
              </xs:sequence>
              <xs:assert test="count(distinct-values(prop2)) = count(prop2)"/>
          </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>      
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

XSD 1.1 is supported by open-source software like Apache Xerces Java https://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/ or Python xmlschema https://pypi.org/project/xmlschema/ or commercial software like Saxon EE.

Comment: Or does he want this:
`<xs:assert test="count(distinct-values(name(*))) = count(*)"/>`

Comment: @SiebeJongebloed, perhaps your interpretation is right, I assumed the sample shown is meant to be valid as `prop2` values are different but perhaps it is an invalid sample having more than one `prop2` child element. I can't tell from the question.

Comment: I know, the OP will know and hopefully clarify .

Comment: Is this possible with XSD 1.0 using unique keyword? It might be asking a lot to bump the required schema version.

Comment: @caduceus, I think for unique constraints you need to spell out the possible child elements (e.g. prop1, prop2, prop3) and then list them in the unique constraint; when I try to put e.g. `<xs:unique name="unique-prop2"><xs:selector xpath="properties"/><xs:field xpath="prop2"/></xs:unique>` on the `root` element declaration for the above sample (and remove the xs:assert) Saxon tells me "The value of a field participating in an identity constraint must have a simple type, or a complex type with simple content. Element prop2 has type xs:anyType", therefore I don't think `xs:unique` works with any